# SQL Error when writing Pandas Dataframe to MySQL datawarehouse

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to load tables into a MySql DWH in the form of a Star Schema. I have created the dimension and fact tables and am now trying to load the date_dim table with a Pandas Dataframe which was created by extracting data from the operational database with the help of sqlalchemy.

Here is where I'm running into problems:

```
with dwh.begin() as cn:

    sql = """INSERT INTO date_dim (id, created_at, month_num, 
    month_day, year, week_day)
    SELECT * 
    FROM date_dim_temp 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS"""

    cn.execute(sql)
```

Running this scrip results in the following error message:

`ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4")`

Assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: is your code properly intended inside the context manager? if not the context manager will run and close the connection for you - you then run your code which will error as the connection has closed.

Comment: That was part of the problem. Many thanks for your comment! Another error has now come to light and is reflected in my edit.

Comment: That I know nothing about - I would do some googling then perhaps edit this question & the title.

Comment: Your SQL query is not valid SQL code. `NOT EXISTS` should be followed by a subquery, like `NOT EXISTS(SELECT ... FROM ...)`. What is the actual intent of your query?